# django - query mutliple models for the same field in each in 1 query

Tags: django, django-queryset

Say I have 3 models (Blog, News, Photos) and i want to get the latest 3 pieces of content regardless of which model they belong to.

With (psuedo) sql I could do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog, news, photo, 
WHERE is_published=True
ORDER by publication_date
LIMIT 3
```

I don't really want to use to use raw sql in Django as i want a query set returned, so is there a way I can make this type of query with Django?

Thanks,

Comment: Well you have to make sacrifices, django can't return a mixed queryset based on different models. Either use raw sql or have three separate queries on respective models.

Comment: Show your models, are blog, news, photo shared foreign key with each other?

Comment: Thanks for your comments - no shared relationship between models.  Happy to make sacrifices, after all Django is amongst the best pieces of software i have ever worked with.  i simply wanted to understand the 'django' solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the 3 models are similar in some way (as they appear to be), the way I would probably do it is by creating a base model and then have the 3 other models inherit from that model.

```
class Publishable(models.Model):
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publication_date = models.DatetimeField()
    ... other fields ...

class Blog(Publishable):
   ...extra fields...

class News(Publishable):
   ...extra fields...

class Photos(Publishable):
   ...extra fields...
```

Then later on, you can do:

```
Publishable.objects.order_by('-publication_date')[:3]
```

If you still need the "type" associated with the retrieved models, check out the [Inheritance Manager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager)

You'll probably want to read about the pros and cons about [Model Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) as well.

Comment: ok thanks for the comment, i see what you're saying here.  The inheritance manager offers an interesting alternative to dropping back to raw slq.  i think given my options here (not much time to refactor everything again), a raw query may be the best alternative but for the next project the manager might be a better option..

Comment: I would like to add that you can still access all of the other models in the same way: `Blog.objects.all()` will still work, so there may not need to be any refactoring. Calling `Publishable.objects.all()` will give you only `Publishable` instances and you don't have access to extra fields defined in the sub classes. A work around is to have a single field that says what `type` that Publishable would be so that you could do a join and get the extra fields. The Inheritance Manager handles all of that nicely for you so you don't have to do the work-around.